# type stack.Stack has no method Push

Tags: go

Writing a stack package.

```
package stack

type Stack struct {
    data []interface{}
}

func (s *Stack) IsEmpty() bool {
    return len(s.data) == 0
}

func (s *Stack) Push(item interface{}) {
    s.data = append(s.data, item)
    //fmt.Println(s.data, item)
}

func (s *Stack) Pop() interface{} {
    if len(s.data) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    index := len(s.data) - 1
    res := s.data[index]
    s.data = s.data[:index]
    return res
}
```

Then tried to call it

```
package main
import (
    s "library/stack"
    t "library/tree"
)
func preorderTraversal(root *t.TreeNode) []int {
    res := make([]int, 0)
    if root == nil {
        return res
    }

    // iterative
    var stack *s.Stack
    stack.Push(root)
    // TODO: more logic
    return res
}

func main() {
    left := t.TreeNode{1, nil, nil}
    right := t.TreeNode{2, nil, nil}
    root := t.TreeNode{0, &left, &right}

    fmt.Println(preorderTraversal(&root))
}
```

But I got an error

```
stack.Push undefined (type *stack.Stack has no field or method Push)
```

What is the issue here?

EDIT:
added the tree package just for convenience

```
package tree

type TreeNode struct {
    Val   int
    Left  *TreeNode
    Right *TreeNode
}
```

added goplayground code based on Cerise Limón play.golang.org/p/E4JXjc-Pd0i

Comment: What exactly is `s` in `var stack *s.Stack`? Is it an alias for the `stack` package?

Comment: What is strange is your error message. From the code you provided the error message should say `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`, as you have a nil pointer in the variable `stack` and you are trying to work with it in the `Push` method.

Comment: @TehSphinX, sorry, I added the package main in the caller. I tried to instantiate a stack in the main package.

Comment: Edit the question to show a [mcve].  The code in the question does not produce the error shown in the question.  https://play.golang.org/p/E4JXjc-Pd0i

Comment: @CeriseLimón, Thank you! Did not know this is how you post multiple modules in playground. Will do in the future! I added this in the post

Comment: @drdot  The code in the playground link does not produce the problem stated in the question.  Please edit the question to show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to instantiate the `stack` variable and not just create a `nil` pointer. Then it should work:

```golang
stack := &s.Stack{}
stack.Push(root)
```

Note:
What confuses me a bit though is the error message. When I run your program it panics: `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Comment: hmm...that did not work for me...getting the same error. Using go version go1.13.3 linux/amd64

Comment: Are you sure, `s.Stack` refers to the `type Stack struct`. From your error it does not seem to do so, and if this answer does not solve your problem, that is the second indicator, that `s.Stack` is NOT referring to the struct in your question.

Comment: Problem solved. I misplaced a diff version of the library with stack API definition starting with lower cases. But thank you for the suggestion! It is what I am really trying to get to anyway!